# Trying to come up with an algorithm to sort to Spanish words

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am writing a program to sort Spanish words.The letters are almost the same as the English alphabet, only with a few exceptions.

```
a,b,c,ch,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,ll,m,n,ñ,o,p,q,r,rr,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z
```

Further, for this problem, assume that any pair of characters which can represent a letter does; for example, the combination ch would always mean the letter ch, not the letter c followed by the letter h.

Now if there wasn't the extra letters, I would be able to sort this easy, but can you guys help me think of an algorithm to help me sort it?

Comment: This sounds like homework. Please tag it as such if it is.

Comment: as far as i know, currently ch, ll and rr get sorted as separate letters.

See http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortograf%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol (in spanish)

Comment: Yes i know, they will be separate, but there are no ASCII codes to represent them

Comment: i mean, currently ch gets sorted between cg and ci, ll gets sorted between lk and lm and rr gets sorted between rq and rs.

Comment: @Zerobu ASCII? Are you stuck in the 80s? We have Unicode now.

Comment: @Nick Unicode? Are you being utopious? As long as I see government letters saying "Dear Mr. D?blinger", I don't believe in "we have unicode now".

Comment: @Michael Yes, we have unicode, and unless you're using a decade-old OS, it works just fine. The problem is people - mostly developers - who are clueless as to its use, and don't understand character encodings.

Comment: Of course you're right. I also use Unicode whenever I can (all the time actually), however, I find myself struggling with poor APIs or whole programs nearly every week. That's why I felt kind of a "not so fast" feeling about your comment, sorry for sounding offensive and offtopic ;-)

Comment: Take a look at the Unicode Collation Algorithm. http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically, language-specific sorting should be done using a [Collator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) for string comparison. For Spanish, you might use:

```
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("es", "ES"));
```

If this is homework, though, I imagine you'd need to come up with something yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply map each letter (starting with the combinations) as a 2 digit number (Starting from 10).

a - 10
b - 11
c - 12
ch - 13
d - 14
etc

The trick is to search for the paired letters (ch, ll, rr) first before you search for the single letter ones.

So - taking a word such as llave the steps would be

23ave
2310ve
231035e
23103515

If you sort the numbers as Strings (so that 1111 comes before 90) then that should produce the correct order.

If you can do a 'sort on' then just pair the number with the original word.  Use the number you created as your sort key.

If you can't do a 'sort on' then you'll need to break the number back to 2 digit codes and convert those back to letters after you've sorted.

Comment: how do you prove that the first step is 23ave and not 21lave?

Comment: Because of the find/replace order.

I could be wrong - my spanish is pretty rough and only extends to a basic use of the language - but I understand that the ll will always mean ʎ, and never just l+l. Similarly, rr is always the double rr, not just two r characters that happen to be together. l + l would be invalid, just as qq wouldn't be a valid combination in English. This may be an over simplification (it's certainly true for all the spanish words I know) but he also stated that the assumption was ok for his problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to account for the specifics of the spellings in the language to decide whether or not "ll", for instance, is "l" "l" or indeed is "ll". This much is obvious to you.

My point in bringing it up is that this is the crux of the problem. You're going to need to pre-process your input so that these ambigous double-letters are encoded as one letter. With a store medium like plain old ASCII text files, this will be impossible.

Your other option is to rely on some statistical liklihood in determining whether a letter pairing is 1 spanish letter or two. By taking into context the contents of the entire word, you can use prior probabilities to determine this. A Bayesian tecnique may work well.

Comment: It would be assumed that a combination of double letters such as "ll" "ch", or "rr", would always mean the Spanish letter of the alphabet, not  two different letters. This is one of the requirements.

Comment: ..then I'm not understanding the problem... can't you just look 1 letter ahead until the end of the word/punctuation to see if this is a letter pair or an ordinary letter?

Comment: OH!! I get what you're saying. You don't know what to do with the fact that there are EXTRA letters because you only know how to do an ASCII comparison. Just add the strings to a hash table or other associative container like a simple array, and the values would be the place in the alphabet.

Comment: The "rr" is a letter in Spanish?

Answer (score 0):

try first parsing each word into an array or list of letter groups, then sorting by comparing the parsed letter groups.

Answer (score 0):

LL is not a letter in Spanish; it used to be considered such due to some Royal Academy of Spanish Language stupidity but they finally admitted it's a digraph. For quite some time, it hasn't been considered a letter in academia, textbooks, Spanish locales, and so on. The confusion came from Spanish letters being so close to phonemes, and LL and CH being used to represent different phonemes.